# getY returns 0.0 when used in fragment

Tags: android

I already tried the answer here: [View getX() and getY() return 0.0 after they have been added to the Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400211/view-getx-and-gety-return-0-0-after-they-have-been-added-to-the-activity)

```
private float foundHeight;
foundationZero = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.foundation_zero);
        foundationZero.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Encuentra la posición de las found para comenzar a posicionar los demás elementos
                foundHeight = foundationZero.getY();
                foundationZero.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                System.out.println("HEIGHT ---->: " + foundHeight);}
        });
```

XML where foundation is:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_fragment_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gameInformationLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/informationMargins"
            android:layout_marginTop = "@dimen/informationMargins"
            android:text="@string/scoreString"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop = "@dimen/informationMargins"
            android:text="@string/movString"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop = "@dimen/informationMargins"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/informationMargins"
            android:text="@string/timeString"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Static Layout -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/redeal_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/foundationBetweenCardMargin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/foundationBetweenCardMargin"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/maxWidthCard"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/maxHeightCard"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src = "@drawable/b1fv"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/foundation_zero"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/foundationBetweenCardMargin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/foundationBetweenCardMargin"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/maxWidthCard"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/maxHeightCard"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/foundation_one"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/foundation_one" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/foundation_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/foundationBetweenCardMargin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/foundationBetweenCardMargin"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/maxWidthCard"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/maxHeightCard"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/foundation_two"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/foundation_two" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/foundation_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/foundationBetweenCardMargin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/foundationBetweenCardMargin"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/maxWidthCard"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/maxHeightCard"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/foundation_three"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/foundation_three" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/foundation_three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/maxWidthCard"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/maxHeightCard"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/foundationBetweenCardMargin" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

In returns 0.0. I need the position of those image views because I'm adding more views programmatically. As can be seen in the code I already tried the solution in the URL but it doesn't work. By the way, I added "used in fragment" in the title because the fact that the above code is written in a Fragment maybe has to do with the fact that it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`View.getY()` does not give you the height of a view, but rather the `Y` position of the top left corner of the view inside the container. Instead, you want to use `View.getHeight()`, which will return you the height of the view in pixels (NOT DP!).